# geolocation check if position is valid

Tags: php, laravel, geolocation, gps, progressive-web-apps

Is there a way to check if the position received from geolocation is valid?

I have an issue that sometimes geolocation gives non correct position. But after a few seconds it gives back the correct one. Is there anyway to check if the received position is correct?

I know about accuracy, but with the non correct position I also receive non correct accuracy.

For example function triggered 2 times in 5 seconds from same position, and first received position is 20 km away from the real one, with decent accuracy.

The code I use
js:

```
        var GPStries = 0;
        var GPStriesTimeout = 10;   
        function getGPSCoordinatesAndSubmit()
        {
            if ("geolocation" in navigator && navigator.geolocation != null) {
                try {
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
                            console.log(position);
                            $('#geolocation_form_latitude').val(position.coords.latitude);
                            $('#geolocation_form_longitude').val(position.coords.longitude);
                            $('#geolocation_form_accuracy').val(position.coords.accuracy);
                            $('#geolocation_form').submit();
                        }, error => {
                            GPStries++;
                            if(GPStries > GPStriesTimeout)
                            {
                                $('#geolocation_form_latitude').val('N/A');
                                $('#geolocation_form_longitude').val('N/A');
                                $('#geolocation_form_accuracy').val('N/A');
                                $('#geolocation_form').submit();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                getGPSCoordinatesAndSubmit();
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 0
                        });
                }
                catch (e) {
                    GPStries++;
                    if(GPStries > GPStriesTimeout)
                    {
                        $('#geolocation_form_latitude').val('N/A');
                        $('#geolocation_form_longitude').val('N/A');
                        $('#geolocation_form_accuracy').val('N/A');
                        $('#geolocation_form').submit();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        getGPSCoordinatesAndSubmit();
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                $('#geolocation_form_latitude').val('N/A');
                $('#geolocation_form_longitude').val('N/A');
                $('#geolocation_form_accuracy').val('N/A');
                $('#geolocation_form').submit();
            }
        }
```

html:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="geolocation_form">
        @csrf
        <input type="hidden" name="latitude" id="geolocation_form_latitude">
        <input type="hidden" name="longitude" id="geolocation_form_longitude">
        <input type="hidden" name="accuracy" id="geolocation_form_accuracy">
 </form>
```

Comment: How do you know it is inaccurate? Can you automate that decision

Comment: Unfortunately it cannot be automated. Same user triggers a button which indicated to send the geolocation data. And there is 20km distance in 5 sec,  which is not possible to walk. Also accuracy is fine (few hundred meters)

Comment: Then you answered your own question. _Unfortunately it cannot be automated._

Comment: "Valid" and "correct" are not the same thing in the first place. A location anywhere in the middle of one of the Earth's oceans is surely _valid_ - but probably less likely, that it is actually _my_ correct location at this point. And you can not tell from _one_ point of information, whether it is "correct", or not - assume I phoned you right now, and told you I was in Argentina. Seconds later, I call you again, and say now I am in Brazil. You have of course no way of telling, whether I gave you "correct" information the first or the second time.

Comment: Can you not force the capture of location to be done twice, compare the 2 locations and maybe compare against the last good one and therefore make an educated guess as to which one is most likely, but of course it will still be a guess that assumes your last good locn was in face sensible

Comment: Or maybe less intrusive, compare the current locn with the last locn, If we have used hyperspace to get there, run the get locn again and see if it is more possible

Comment: The error margin of 20km seems a bit weird, I'd say. Is it really that much? Especially if the accuracy is claimed to be few hundred meters. GeolocationCoordinates.accuracy claims to be 95% confidence level.

Comment: the first one is a really good idea, to make a educated guess, I can monitor for few seconds the geolocation datas and then select the one which was presented most.
The second solution could work as well, but unfortunately most of the cases it is only triggered once.

Comment: @Hendrik yes, without doubt, although the phones using the application is relative cheap